# Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT("keyspace".user_product_info) <->model.user.UserProductInfo]

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

Issue :

I am using **DataStax Java Driver 4.9** I have declared a UDT user_product_info in my keyspace  and this uses nested UDTs......while running the program it shows Codec not found when executing the following line

**

```
PreparedStatement preparedUpdateFriendRating = session.prepare("UPDATE friend_rating SET user_product_infos=:userproductinfos WHERE user_id=:userId ;");
preparedUpdateFriendRating.bind(new ArrayList(userProductInfo), id);
```

**

following is the shema.cql

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT exists user_product_info (id text,short_product frozen < short_product>,test set < text >,ratings list< frozen < rating > >);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists friend_rating(user_id text,user_product_infos list < frozen < user_product_info >>,PRIMARY KEY (user_id));

CREATE TYPE IF NOT exists short_product (name text,specs SET < text >,img text);
```

With corresponding java class

```
//------------------------------------USER PRODUCT INFO-----------


@SchemaHint(targetElement = UDT)
public class UserProductInfo {

    @CqlName("id")
    private String productId;

    @CqlName("short_product")
    private ShortProduct shortProduct;

    @CqlName("test")
    private Set<String> test;

    @CqlName("ratings")
    private List<Rating> ratings;

    public UserProductInfo() {}

//with getters and setters
}

//---------------------------------------SHORT PRODUCT----------------

@SchemaHint(targetElement = UDT)
public class ShortProduct {
    @CqlName("name")
    private String name;

    @CqlName("specs")
    private Set<String> specs;

    @CqlName("img")
    private String imageUrl;

    public ShortProduct() {}
//with getters and setters
}

//--------------------------------------FRIEND RATING TABLE-------------------

@SchemaHint(targetElement = TABLE)
public class FriendRating {
    @PartitionKey
    @CqlName("user_id")
    private String userId;

    @CqlName("user_product_infos")
    private List<UserProductInfo> userProductInfos;

//with getters and setters
}
'''
```

**with following stack trace:**

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT("keyspace".user_product_info) <-> model.user.UserProductInfo]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:609) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:196) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:567) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963) ~[java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:258) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.ValuesHelper.encodePreparedValues(ValuesHelper.java:112) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultPreparedStatement.bind(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: If you are using spring data repositories, this issue is fixed now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1473

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 alternatives to solve this problem:

- Implement custom code for your UDT as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-java-to-cql-mappings-with-mapping-codec) (I don't want to copy code from it).  It's required because you're using core API (`session.execute`)
- Switch to use [object mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/mapper/) - you'll work with your objects directly, loading and saving them, etc.. You already started to annotate your objects with `@CqlName`, but they aren't used because you need to setup preprocessor for generation of the code based on this annotations.  (you also don't need to have annotations for simple field names, like, `names`, etc. You also may not need this for more complex names, because object mapper has different naming translators, like, camel case to snake case, etc.)